# Unable to connect when I start MySql from XAMPP

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I recently started a project and I used a large table to import on phpmyadmin. After I changed the sizes from php.ini, I tried to connect to phpmyadmin,but `Unable to connect` error appeared. Here is the recent log:

```
2016-07-05 22:22:39 5052 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2016-07-05 22:22:40 5676 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2016-07-05 22:22:40 5052 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2016-07-05 22:22:42 5052 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 4456833
2016-07-05 22:22:42 5052 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete

2016-07-05 22:25:13 1464 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2016-07-05 22:25:13 5220 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-07-05 22:25:13 5220 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-07-05 22:25:13 5220 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2016-07-05 22:25:13 5220 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-07-05 22:25:13 5220 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2016-07-05 22:25:13 5220 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-07-05 22:25:13 5220 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2016-07-05 22:25:13 5220 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-07-05 22:25:13 5220 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-07-05 22:25:14 5220 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-07-05 22:25:14 5220 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2016-07-05 22:25:14 5220 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.26-74.0 started; log sequence number 4456833
2016-07-05 22:25:14 2732 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2016-07-05 22:25:14 5220 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2016-07-05 22:25:14 5220 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2016-07-05 22:25:14 5220 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.9-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
2016-07-05 22:27:32 2344 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Normal shutdown

2016-07-05 22:27:32 2344 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2016-07-05 22:27:32 1160 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2016-07-05 22:27:32 2344 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2016-07-05 22:27:33 2344 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 4456843
2016-07-05 22:27:33 2344 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete

2016-07-05 22:27:42 12fc InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2016-07-05 22:27:42 4860 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-07-05 22:27:42 4860 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-07-05 22:27:42 4860 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2016-07-05 22:27:42 4860 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-07-05 22:27:42 4860 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2016-07-05 22:27:42 4860 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-07-05 22:27:42 4860 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2016-07-05 22:27:42 4860 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-07-05 22:27:42 4860 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-07-05 22:27:43 4860 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-07-05 22:27:43 4860 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2016-07-05 22:27:43 4860 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.26-74.0 started; log sequence number 4456843
2016-07-05 22:27:43 3052 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2016-07-05 22:27:43 4860 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2016-07-05 22:27:43 4860 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2016-07-05 22:27:44 4860 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
```

If someone could explain me what should I do,it would be great.

Comment: mysql is ready at the end of the log. can you run mysqlworkbench see the status?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem was that I had the Antivirus running. Apparently it conflicted with XAMPP.